# How to use SQL function LIKE properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm encountering a problem doing SQL requests. Indeed, i'm trying to get statistics from my MYSQL database and in order to do this i'm executing several similar queries to get informations on entries that share the same "universe". I call universe multiple categories that share the same pattern(see below).

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) FROM offer AS o, offerattributes AS oa 
WHERE o.offer_id=oa.offer_id AND o.cat LIKE '1%' AND oa.attribute_id='status_indexer';
```

This first query is used to get informations on universe 1 categories. Every "cat" from this universe share two different patterns:

1) 11***** (* are numbers)

2) 10*****

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) FROM offer AS o, offerattributes AS oa 
WHERE o.offer_id=oa.offer_id AND o.cat LIKE '10%' AND oa.attribute_id='status_indexer';
```

This second one is used to get informations on universe 10 categories. As for the universe 1, each "cat" from universe 10 shares two different patterns:

1) 100*****

2) 101*****

The problem I have is that those two queries both look for categories in universe 1 and 10. I've read the doc from [MySQL treating about the LIKE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html), looked up over the internet and I havn't found how to solve this problem.

Comment: **** contains only numbers and yes the length of the string for universe 10 is one character longer than universe 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following would work for you for universe 1:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) 
FROM offer o
INNER JOIN offerattributes oa ON o.offer_id = oa.offer_id
WHERE o.cat LIKE '1%' AND oa.attribute_id = 'status_indexer'
AND LEN(o.cat) = 7
```

and universe 10:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) 
FROM offer o
INNER JOIN offerattributes oa ON o.offer_id = oa.offer_id
WHERE o.cat LIKE '10%' AND oa.attribute_id = 'status_indexer'
AND LEN(o.cat) = 8
```